# Run mapper job on specific node

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is it possible to specify on which nodes to run specific mapper jobs?
Have distributed data on nodes and want to run jobs on the nodes containing that data

Comment: Why do you want to run job on a specific node?

Comment: to avoid data travel from node holding data to mapper node

Comment: Hadoop automatically takes care of it during scheduling. User need not do anything.

Comment: I'm going to feed data from cassandra database.
how does it know what data i'm going to feed into it?

Comment: For HDFS block processing Hadoop takes care of data locality while processing the data. But, I don't think it's done for Cassandra as an input. When there is affinity for job to node, then fault tolerance has to be taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a reliable way to make sure a map task runs on a specific node.  You can create a custom `InputFormat` and override `InputFormat.getLocations()` to return only the host name of the node you want that split to run on.  However, these locations are merely suggestions to the MR framework and it can choose to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Hadoop out of the box doesn't support it. But, this feature is supported in MapR distribution ([1](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Label-based+Scheduling)).